# For what reason can ActionCable stop working partially and only locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

There is one place in the app that uses the ActionCable to update the content (post page). This functionality worked and there was no point in testing it locally every time.

But yesterday I found that it doesn't work, but only locally. On the server, the same application code works successfully.

I've double-checked everything more than ten times, the problem is not on the back end. On the side of the back end job or worker from Sidekiq, they successfully execute the code:

```rb
ActionCable.server.broadcast(
  "post_update:#{post.to_gid_param}",
  {
    post_id: post.id
  }.to_json
)
```

And `stream_from` successfully executed in `subscribed` in `PostUpdateChannel`.

And even on the front end there is a subscription to `PostUpdateChannel`. That is, the front end shows me what it always showed in the browser console:

> PostUpdateChannel: connected()

```js
channels: {
  [CHANNEL_NAME]: {
    connected() {
      console.info(
        `${CHANNEL_NAME}: connected()`
      )
    },

    // ...
```

But this method stopped working:

```js
received(data) {
  const json = JSON.parse(data)

  console.info(
    `${CHANNEL_NAME}: received()`,
    json
  )

  // ...
```

But at the same time, the same code works successfully on the server...

In general, my question is - what could it be? I see no errors. Back end works successfully. The front end also seems to work, but it is precisely locally that it cannot receive data from the back end

---

Rails 6.1.3.2, ActionCable 6.1.3.2, Webpacker 5.4.0

@rails/webpacker 5.4.0, @rails/actioncable 6.1.3, actioncable-vue 2.4.6

Comment: did you see the log `[ActionCable] Broadcasting to ...` ?

Comment: @LamPhan This is not in the logs either locally or on the server. But everything works on the server.

Comment: of course there's no debug log on production server, but on local (i assume on development env) if those logs not show, it's mean `Broadcaster` is not broadcast message.

Comment: @LamPhan Interesting. Why might this be happening? When subscribing, the front end transmits the ID to the Channel - I checked that.

Comment: maybe `adapter: async` is the cause, iam not sure, you can try `redis` on your local.

Comment: @LamPhan Strange situation. I have not touched these settings and the code associated with it. I need to update everything on redis for the local environment, as on the server? One more thing - workers are working. Sending mail, doing background processing - it all works locally.

Comment: @LamPhan Yes, replacing the adapter with redis fixed the situation locally. But I still don't understand why the async adapter broke. Thanks for the advice. Perhaps further work locally with the redis adapter will be even better (similar to the server).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by replacing this:

```yaml
# config/cable.yml

development:
  adapter: async
```

On this:

```yaml
# config/cable.yml

development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```